# Cannot review a low quality post that I've flagged earlier

Tags: bug, review, low-quality-posts

I'd like to mention that this is not the first time that I've encountered this.

The issue is that if I attempt to review a low quality post that I've flagged earlier, I will not be available to review it unless I press "Looks OK", which makes no sense. If I click "Recommend Close", it simply says that I've already flagged it, as shown in this screenshot:

[image: Low quality post bug]

In the first post reviews, if I've already upvoted/commented/flagged on a post, I will be available to press on "I'm Done", which should also be possible in the low quality post reviews.

Comment: The bug in my opinion is, that you should not get that item to begin with.

Comment: @ShadowWizard That would indeed solve the issue.

Comment: Well, turns out it's a long time bug that never got any official attention.

Comment: Oops, didn't see it.

Comment: @Simon all good, sometimes it's hard to find dupes. Anyway you can click the "I agree" button in the banner on top of your question to insta-close it.

Comment: @TildalWave yes because no software company in history has ever had outstanding bugs older than 2 years...

Comment: @ShadowWizard Well, I'm not sure if I want to do that, Tildal does have a point, maybe this will remind them.

Comment: No, correct way is bumping existing reports with edits/answers/bounties and not posting new reports on purpose or leaving same reports open.

Comment: Ok, let's do this then.